# Hosting Angular Application Without Node server

Tags: angular, apache, tomcat

Im looking to host my Angular6 dist folder to Tomcat server without using node.js server

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to deploy application Tomcat server.

**Step 1:** Create an angular application build using below command

```
ng build --prod --base-href /App/
```

> **–base-href**: context root of your application, basically URL with the
>   help of which you will navigate your application.
>
> **–prod:** value for environment( prod for production or dev for development).

**Step 2:** Navigate inside the **dist** folder and rename the folder with your project name

**Step 3:** Install tomcat if not installed on your machine [from here](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi)

**Step 4:** Now copy the renamed folder inside the **webapps** (You can locate this folder inside your tomcat installed directory.

**Step 5:** Now start the tomcat server by double-clicking on Tomcat8.exe which is inside the bin folder.

**Step 5:** Navigate to the local URL with the app name you provided while building the angular application. http://localhost:4040/App/

Hope this help!